# How to watch hashmap variables in PerlDebug in vscode?

Tags: perl, debugging, visual-studio-code, hashmap, watch

I am doing remote debugging with PerlDebug in vscode. I ran

```
PERLDB_OPTS="RemotePort=localmachine:5000 perl -d myscript.pl
```

on "remotemachine" than I ran vscode PerlDebug on "localmachine" and was able to step over lines of script.

But how to watch variables now? I can watch some variables like `part1`, `part2` and `value` in attached example, but I can't watch `$events`, probably because it is a hashmap.

[image]

Also it displays nothing in `VARIABLES` pane.

Is it possible to see hashmap vars here?

Comment: Sorry it was `-d`

Comment: According to the [description](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mortenhenriksen.perl-debug) of the extension: *"TODO: Watching variables doesn't create actual expression watchers yet - need more APIs for actually maintaining the list of expressions to watch."*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of entering `$events` for the watch expression, try entering `%events`. Then the extension will understand that it is a hash map and not a scalar variable.

**Note**: When I tested this, I was not able to show array and hash refs in the `WATCH` panel. So if `$h` is a hash ref, adding `%$h` as a watch expression, does not work (it does not show nested values). I was however able to work around this by declaring an alias to `$h` like this:

```
use v5.26;
use feature qw(declared_refs refaliasing);
my \%hh = \%$h;
```

and then watch `%hh` instead of `%$h`. This worked for array refs also.